# Problems in update and delete on Sequelize js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having some troubles when trying to delete or update an row using the Sequelize JS.
When I try to do something like this ( on update ):

```
Embed.find(parseInt(req.body.id, 10)).success(function(embed) {
    embed.updateAttributes({
        NOME : req.body.name,
        EMBED : req.body.embed
    }).success(function() {
        res.json({"success" : true});
    }).error(function() {
        res.json({"success" : false});
     });
 });
```

Or ( on delete ):

```
Embed.find(parseInt(req.body.id, 10)).success(function(embed){
    embed.destroy().success(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        if(e && e.deletedAt) {
            res.json({"success": true});
        }
    }).error(function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
}).error(function(){
    res.json({"success": false});
});
```

It show an error:

```
return (typeof obj == 'object') && !obj.hasOwnProperty('length')
```

TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null
    at Object.isHash

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: which version are you using? what is embed in the second line?

Comment: Hi. I'm using the 1.3.7 version. "embed" would be the answer from the find method ( which returns the correct row ).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using wrong. If you are using `find()` method, you must pass an object inside it. Like the following;

```
Embed
  .findAll({ "id": parseInt(req.body.id) })
  .then(function(embed) { ... });
```

And this code returns an array from promise. So you can't use it directly as `embed.updateAttributes(...)`. You have to use like this; `embed[0].updateAttributes(...)`.

Or you can use like this;

```
Embed
  .findOne({ "id": parseInt(req.body.id) })
  .then(function(embed) { embed.updateAttributes(...); });
```

Because `findOne()` returns just an object which you find.

And.. I saw now, this post is very old. And .find() method was deprecated. So I replaced `find()` method with `findAll()`. I think these are doing same process.